# How can I static cast the output of the >> operator in c++?

Tags: c++

Or perform any function really.

Currently I have some code that looks a bit like this:

```
int temp_int;
streamer >> temp_int;
finalObj = static_cast<CustomType>(temp_int);
```

ints can be cast into CustomTypes (obviously) and finalObj is of type CustomType

streamer's >> operator has not been set up to work with CustomType. Changing this is outside my area of control.

Im looking for a way to put the above code in a single line and avoid using a temporary variable.

When putting custom types back into the streamer, I use this:

```
streamer << static_cast<int>(someObj);
```

Thats a lot neater. And it would be great to have the instreaming and outstreaming look symmetrical for easier reading.

Thanks

Comment: You could implement the `>>` and `<<` operators for `CustomType`. Also, you can add the `>>` operator for `streamer`

Comment: You don't need access to the class file to implement `>>` for `streamer` and `CustomType`

Comment: Good point. Covered correctly in answer, so I'll just nuke that before some kid finds it.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement an `operator>>` and make sure name lookup finds it.

```
struct CustomType
{
    int m_value;
    CustomType(int v = 0)
        : m_value(v)
    {}

    operator int() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }
};
```

```
namespace
{
    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, CustomType& out)
    {
        int temp;
        s >> temp;
        out = temp;
        return s;
    }
}

int main()
{
    CustomType finalObj;
    std::cin >> finalObj;
    std::cout << finalObj << '\n';
}
```

Alternatively, if you aren't sure, if `operator>>` has already been implemented somewhere in an undesired manner, you could create a wrapper type and implement `operator>>` for it.

```
namespace
{
    class CustomTypeParsingWrapper
    {
    public:
        CustomTypeParsingWrapper(CustomType& target)
            : m_target(target)
        {
        }

        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, CustomTypeParsingWrapper const& wrapper)
        {
            int temp;
            s >> temp;
            wrapper.m_target = temp;
            return s;
        }

    private:
        CustomType& m_target;
    };
}

int main()
{
    CustomType finalObj;
    std::cin >> CustomTypeParsingWrapper(finalObj);
    std::cout << finalObj << '\n';
}
```

Note: The use of the anonymous namespace here is only to avoid conflicts with implementations provided to other translation units. If you want to reuse `operator>>`, you should put it in the same namespace as `CustomType` to allow Argument Dependent Lookup to find it. A customTypeParsingWrapper intended to be reused could be put in a namespace of your choice...

Answer (score -3):

One way to achieve what you want is to overload not only `<<` and `>>` operators, but also the cast operator.

One way to do that is to overload the `int()` operator for `CustomType`. This way, you can use put your value back into the streamer easily:

```cpp
class CustomType
{
private:
    int _value;
public:
    CustomType(const int &value) : _value(value) {}

    // ...
    operator int() const { return _value; }

};
```

This way, the compiler will find the appropriate cast from `CustomType` to `int` when using the `<<` operator:

```cpp
streamer << someObj;
```

will implicitly cast to `int`.

Similar overloads could be implemented to achieve the results.

Here is a full snipped to test this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class CustomType
{
private:
    int _value;
public:
    CustomType(const int &value) : _value(value) {}

    // ...
    operator int() const { return _value; }

};

int main() {

  auto someObj = CustomType(10);
  std::cout << someObj;
}
```

This prints `10` to the standard output.

Comment: This returns an `int` *by value*. He wants to be able to manipulate CustomType by *reading* from a stream, not writing. Implicit conversions are unhelpful.